# User can't click more than once in a time-frame

Tags: javascript, time

Is there an easy way to prevent a click event from being triggered more than once in a time-frame.

E.g. the user can only trigger an event by clicking on a button after 2 seconds have passed.

I can think of a solution by using *setInterval* and a variable to track the time. But is there a better way?

Comment: `setTimeout` is more appropiate. And `variable`.

Comment: Asking for **better ways** is subjective not an on topic question. Your question, as it stands at the moment, seems to want to discuss different ways of fulfilling your requirements rather than asking a specific question in the context of a specific implementation. There is many ways achieving this and many opinions on what is **best** If you think `setInterval` might work, give it a shot and see if it works for you. If you have issue getting it to work, post your code and we can help sort it out. It also helps to check the documentation on the different options.

Comment: A lot depends as well on what you are trying to achieve specifically and why. If the intend is to simply prevent someone from spamming a button, disable the button until the request is done. Exact times would be irrelevant then as the request might take longer. If the button returns data from a server, cache the data and clear it out every few seconds, then either return chached data or re-query if no data is in the cache. There is many more fitting solutions depending on what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: @Nope. Okay point taken thanks. I should have defined my question better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already got an `onclick` event handler, you can integrate the behavior into that:

```
var lastValidClick = 0;

button.onclick = function(event) {
    if (Date.now() - lastValidClick < 2000) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    lastValidClick = Date.now();
    // proceed to do whatever you need to do on click
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `setTimeout`, also you can use disabled state instead of internal variable:

```js
let timeframe = 3000;
document.querySelector('#dis_btn')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.target.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => event.target.disabled = false, timeframe);
  
  console.log('clicked');
});

document.querySelector('#int_btn')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.disable_flag) return false;
  event.target.disable_flag = true;
  setTimeout(() => event.target.disable_flag = false, timeframe);
  
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<button id=dis_btn>Disable</button>
<button id=int_btn>Internal flag</button>
```

Some generalized solution can look like:

```js
function addThrottleEventListener(el, eventName, handler, timeframe) {
  let last = Date.now() - timeframe;
  el.addEventListener(eventName, event => {
    let now = Date.now();
    if (now < last + timeframe) return;
    last = now;
    handler(event);
  });
}
// same, with setTimeout
function on(el, name, handler, timeframe) {
  let disabled = false;
  el.addEventListener(name, event => {
    if (disabled) return;
    disabled = true;
    setTimeout(() => disabled = false, timeframe);
    handler(event);
  });
}

const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
addThrottleEventListener(btn1, 'click', () => console.log('1 clicked'), 2000);
on(btn2, 'click', () => console.log('2 clicked'), 2000);
```

```html
<button id=btn1>Click</button>
<button id=btn2>Click</button>
```